# Reading newline-separated items from file

Tags: c, gcc, hash, fgets, unsigned-char

I've a problem with my .c program. I'll explain it :

- I have 2 files (listePassword.txt and system_1.phl)
- First file contains 10 passwords (like 123456, 12345678, admin, etc)
- The second contains 10 hashs (f31041d6d9c2031086bfe561d8e4b63f or 77b6508f00223102d793837b9dd60358 for example)

I made a function to read lines on these files (1 word / hash by line). 
The code :

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

   FILE *f = fopen("listePasswords.txt","r");
   FILE *S1 = fopen("system_1.phl", "r");

   unsigned char passwords[10][32]; 
   unsigned char system_1[10][32];

   lireFichier(f, passwords);
   lireFichier(S1, system_1);
```

And now the function :

```
void lireFichier(FILE *f, unsigned char (*resultats)[32]) {
    int i = 0;
    if(f){
        while(fgets(resultats[i], sizeof(resultats[i]), f) != 0) {
            printf("%s\n", resultats[i]);
            i++;
            fgetc(f);
        }
    }
}
```

The program doesn't read first char of each password except the first word, and I don't have all lines of the system_1.phl.

Can you help me a little ? :D 
(don't help with "{" or "}", I probably didn't paste them all).

Thanks guys ! (sorry, I'm French and not so good in English ahah).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `fgetc(f)` in the loop. That's reading the first character of the next line.

I assume you intended it to read the newline at the end of the line. But `fgets()` includes that in its result, so you don't need to skip over it. Instead, you should remove it from `resultsat[i]`:

```
while (fgets(resultsat[i], sizeof resultat[i], f) != 0) {
    int len = strlen(resultat[i]);
    if (len > 0 && resultat[i][len-1] == '\n') {
        resultat[i][len-1] = '\0';
    }
    printf("%s\n", resultat[i]);
    i++;
}
```

You also need to change `[32]` in the array declarations to at least `[34]`. Your hashes are 32 characters long, but `fgets()` will read the following newline and also needs to add a null byte to terminate the string. So you need at least 2 more bytes in the arrays.

Comment: Your answer fix the problem with passwords (it's a mistake from me, i forget i try to use fgetc to skip the last char, but it's okay). 
But the problem is already here with hashes... 
When i use what you wrote, i've this result : 
lireFichier(S1, system_1);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
 printf("Taille : %d + %s\n", strlen(system_1[i]), system_1[i]);
}

Taille : 31 + f31041d6d9c2031086bfe561d8e4b63
Taille : 1 + f
Taille : 31 + 77b6508f00223102d793837b9dd6035
Taille : 1 + 8

In my file, i've : 
f31041d6d9c2031086bfe561d8e4b63f
77b6508f00223102d793837b9dd60358
what am I forget?

Comment: Your hashes are 32 characters long, so the arrays need to be `[33]` to allow room for the null byte.

Comment: Yeah, it's really good now ! 
But I see an other problem with my file, so I open it with an Hex editor. The strings are : 
f31041d6d9c2031086bfe561d8e4b63f.
77b6508f00223102d793837b9dd60358.

So, i need to read 34 char, and not 33. But with your help, it's fine now ! 
Thank you so much :D